# how can I set a form at top left side of a screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to develop a windows application  so I Like When execute my project want to show a form  top-left side of a screen. I don't know how to do this please help me ....

Comment: This is not how SO works, you need to do your own research and write your own code, you can only ask questions here when you are really stuck.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984420(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This link is more helpful@fdfey:):)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add code in your form method like..

public Form1()

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
```

its work for me...

Answer (score 0):

In your form load put this line :

```
this.Location = new Point(0, 0);
```

Comment: Why people just copy the answer of other ?!I am the first giving then answer